# ajax post no update in django template

Tags: ajax, django

I want to post some text in django with ajax,and save the input data,show the data in same page and no refresh,like twitter.

my js:

```
$('#SumbitButton').click(function(){
        var data_1 = $('#data_1').val()
        var data_2 = $('#data_2').val()
        var data_3 = $('#data_3').val()
        var data_4 = $('#data_4').val()
        var user = $('#AuthorName').text()
        var authorprotrait = $('#UserProprait').html()
    if(data_1.length>0){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/post/',
            data:{'data_1':data_1,'data_2':data_2,'data_3':data_3,'data_4':data_4}, 
            async: false,
            error: function(msg){alert('Fail')},
            success:  function(msg){
                $('#TopicWrap').prepend("<div class='topic-all even'><div class='topic-left'><div class='topic-author'><div class='topic-author-protrait'>"+authorprotrait+"</div><div class='topic-author-nickname'>"+authorname+"</div></div></div><div class='topic-right'><div class='topic-meta'><span class='topic-datetime'></span></div><div class='topic-content-wrap'><div class='topic-content'>"+msg+"</div></div></div><div class='clearfix'></div></div>");
                $('#data_1').val('');   
                $('#data_2').val('');
                $('#data_3').val('');
                $('#data_4').val('');   
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('The data_1's length  error ！'+data_1.length);  
    }   
});
```

and the html:

```
<div id="TopicTextarea">
    <div>
        data1:<input tabindex="4" id="data_1"  type="text" name="data1"  value="" maxlength="6"  placeholder=""/></br>
        data2:<input tabindex="4" id="data_2"  type="text" name="data2"  value="" maxlength="8"  placeholder=""/></br>
        data3:<input tabindex="4" id="data_3"  type="text" name="data3"  value="" maxlength="10"  placeholder=""/></br>
        data4:<input tabindex="4" id="data_4"  type="text" name="data4"  value="" maxlength="10"  placeholder=""/>  
        <div id="TopicFormControl">
        <button type="button" id="SumbitButton" class="button orange">sumbit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
　　 <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div id="TopicWrap">
{% include 'topics.html'%}
</div>
```

and the views:

```
@login_required
def post(request):

    assert(request.method=='POST' and request.is_ajax()==True)
    data_1 = smart_unicode(request.POST['data_1'])
    data_2 = smart_unicode(request.POST['data_2'])
    data_3 = smart_unicode(request.POST['data_3'])
    data_4 = smart_unicode(request.POST['data_4'])

    data_obj = DataPool(user=request.user,data_1=data_1,data_2=data_2,data_3=data_3, data_4=data_4)
    data_obj.save()

    content = '"+data_3+" 　"+data_4+"　"+data_1+"("+data_2+")' 

    response = HttpResponse(cgi.escape(content))

    return response
```

when I input the data and click the sumbit button,it can save the data ,but it can't show the data.what's wrong in my code?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, use something like [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) to test that your view is returning what you expect. Only then should you start building the AJAX part.

As for what's wrong... it's a bit difficult to say since you just write that it "can't show the data" instead of saying what it's actually doing. I suspect it has to do with this line in your view:

```
content = '"+data_3+" 　"+data_4+"　"+data_1+"("+data_2+")'
```

It's not really clear to me what you think this would do, but what it actually does is:

```
>>> '"+data_3+" 　"+data_4+"　"+data_1+"("+data_2+")'
'"+data_3+" \xe3\x80\x80"+data_4+"\xe3\x80\x80"+data_1+"("+data_2+")'
```

That is to say that it produces a string containing the substrings `"data_3"` (etc..) It **does not** include the submitted data.

Comment: I want to save the data ,at the same time,add the data with some format on the page and not refresh the page.How should I do？

Comment: You have the correct method, generally. You need to test each component individually, e.g. with Poster, to see that it's working. Is your view being properly called? Is your object getting saved? Is your view returning the correct response? Is that response being correctly displayed? If one of these is not working, and you want help with it, you need to be specific about **how** it is not working. "can't show the data" is not sufficient to be able to answer. Is the data being returned? Are you getting a javascript error? Something else?